# Japanese Character in birt report

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, birt

I am using birt report engine to generate some pdf report in java.

I tried to look at the problem in all aspects without any success.

I have a pdf report which contain different graph and try to generate it in japanese.
Japan text have no problem to be rendered but on the axes of my graph, I don't succeeded to draw japanese character. I have instead some small square. I have the same problem if I generate a doc report

On my local server, I succeded to generate my report but not when I deploy my application on Ubuntu server.

I use the Font sansserif which seems to be connected to Helvetica in my fontConfig.xml

On my server I installed ttf-takao and ttf-msttcorefonts.

I am a little surprised that it work for text but not in graphes.

Is it a problem in my font conf on server, or have I to edit fontConfig.xml?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find one solution to my problem.

fontConfig.xml was fine defined but I didn't configure my jre to accept japanese character.
Charts are firstly designed by Java chart engine and convert in image to be added to the birt report.

Here is the different references I used :
http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/34743-japanese-character-in-pdf-report/

http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~ik2r-myr/kanji/german/linos_g.htm